# ZipEntry.STORED for files that are already compressed?

Tags: java, zipoutputstream

I am using a `ZipOutputStream` to zip up a bunch of files that are a mix of already zipped formats as well as lots of large highly compressible formats like plain text.

Most of the already zipped formats are large files and it makes no sense to spend cpu and memory on recompressing them since they never get smaller and sometimes get slightly large on the rare occasion.

I am trying to use `.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED)` when I detect a pre-compressed file but it complains that I need to supply the `size, compressedSize and crc` for those files.

I can get it work with the following approach but this requires that I read the file **twice**. Once to calculate the `CRC32` then again to actually copy the file into the `ZipOutputStream`.

```
// code that determines the value of method omitted for brevity
if (STORED == method)
{
    fze.setMethod(STORED);
    fze.setCompressedSize(fe.attributes.size());
    final HashingInputStream his = new HashingInputStream(Hashing.crc32(), fis);
    ByteStreams.copy(his,ByteStreams.nullOutputStream());
    fze.setCrc(his.hash().padToLong());
}
else
{
    fze.setMethod(DEFLATED);
}
zos.putNextEntry(fze);
ByteStreams.copy(new FileInputStream(fe.path.toFile()), zos);
zos.closeEntry();
```

### Is there a way provide this information without having to read the input stream twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short Answer:

I could not determine a way to read the files only once and calculate the `CRC` with the standard library given the time I had to solve this problem.

I did find an optimization that decreased the time by about `50%` on average.

I pre-calculate the `CRC` of the files to be stored concurrently with an `ExecutorCompletionService` limited to `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` and wait until they are done. The effectiveness of this varies based on the number of files that need the `CRC` calculated. With the more files, the more benefit.

Then in the `.postVisitDirectories()` I wrap a `ZipOutputStream` around a `PipedOutputStream` from a `PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream` pair running on a temporary `Thread` to convert the `ZipOutputStream` to an `InputStream` I can pass into the `HttpRequest` to upload the results of the `ZipOutputStream` to a remote server while writing all the precalculated `ZipEntry/Path` objects serially.

This is good enough for now, to process the `300+GB` of immediate needs, but when I get to the `10TB` job I will look at addressing it and trying to find some more advantages without adding too much complexity.

If I come up with something substantially better time wise I will update this answer with the new implementation.

#### Long answer:

I ended up writing a clean room `ZipOutputStream` that supports multipart zip files, intelligent compression levels vs `STORE` and was able to calculate the `CRC` as I read and then write out the metadata at the end of the stream.

---

#### Why ZipOutputStream.setLevel() swapping will not work:

> The `ZipOutputStream.setLevel(NO_COMPRESSION/DEFAULT_COMPRESSION)`
>   hack is not a viable approach. I did extensive tests on hundreds of
>   gigs of data, thousands of folders and files and the measurements were
>   conclusive. It gains nothing over calculating the `CRC` for the
>   `STORED` files vs compressing them at `NO_COMPRESSION`. It is actually
>   **slower** by a large margin!
>
> In my tests the files are on a **network mounted drive** so reading
>   the files already compressed files **twice** over the network to
>   calculate the `CRC` then again to add to the `ZipOutputStream` was as
>   fast or faster than just processing all the files once as `DEFLATED`
>   and changing the `.setLevel()` on the `ZipOutputStream`.
>
> There is no local filesystem caching going on with the network access.
>   This is a worse case scenario, processing files on the local disk will
>   be much much faster because of local filesystem caching.
>
> So this hack is a naive approach and is based on false assumptions. It is processing the
>   data through the compression algorithm even at `NO_COMPRESSION` level
>   and the overhead is higher than reading the files twice.

Answer (score 1):

> I could not determine a way to read the files only once and calculate the `CRC` with the standard library given the time I had to solve this problem.
>
> I did find an optimization that decreased the time by about `50%` on average.
>
> I pre-calculate the `CRC` of the files to be stored concurrently...

I've measured about the same improvement, compared to alternating the `ZipOutputStream.setLevel(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION)` and `ZipOutputStream.setLevel(Deflater.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION)`, without concurrent CRC calculation using:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

...

    void addTo(ZipOutputStream zipOut, Path file) throws IOException {
        try (FileChannel fch = FileChannel.open(file)) {
            MappedByteBuffer buf = fch.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fch.size());
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(relativize(file));
            entry.setLastModifiedTime(Files.getLastModifiedTime(file));
            if (entry.getName().endsWith(".zip")
                    || entry.getName().endsWith(".gz")) {
                entry.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED);
                entry.setSize(buf.remaining());
                entry.setCrc(checkSum(buf));
            }
            zipOut.putNextEntry(entry);
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            WritableByteChannel zipCh = Channels.newChannel(zipOut);
            zipCh.write(buf);
            zipOut.closeEntry();
        }
    }

    static long checkSum(ByteBuffer buf) {
        CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
        int mark = buf.position();
        crc.update(buf);
        buf.position(mark);
        return crc.getValue();
    }
```

(The `relativize(Path) : String` method is left out of the example.)

The `CRC32` class provides very efficient [`update(ByteBuffer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/CRC32.html#update%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) method for use with memory-mapped (direct) file buffers.